# AFNetworking sending Bool/Integer in post request

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, post, afnetworking

I am sending a bool value and a Integer value to server using post request. Request parameter below

```
{
    photo = "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.jpeg";
    "photo_id" = 126383;
    selected = 1;
}
```

Here "photo_id" is Integer and "selected" is Boolean, But in backend both are String. can any one help me in fixing this. Below is the code of post request

```
[self.networkManager startPOSTRequestWithAPI:aEditUserInfoAPI andParameters:self.paramsDict withSuccess:^(NSDictionary *responseDictionary) {

 }
 andFailure:^(NSString *errorMessage) {

}];
```

Here self.networkManager is object of AFNetworking class

Comment: Use NSNumber to convert from Bool/Int to String.                           NSInteger id = 126383;
NSNumber *xNSNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:id];
NSString *xString = [xNSNumber stringValue];

Comment: Both Boolean and Integer are in NSNumber format. But in backend its string.

Comment: While creating the request parameter make sure it is always string. This is a client side fix. In future and on other mobile platforms, it is better to fix it on the server side.

Comment: But same call in Android is working fine

Comment: Convert it to string first.Then send it.

Comment: If you give response I will help you.

Comment: Its not about the response. Backend is expecting Integer and I am sending Integer but backend is receiving as string.